# Book suggestion : geometric approach to electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, education

I´m looking for a book on electromagnetism that is introducing the topic from a geometric point of view, focusing more on the theoretical structure than on the application.

Comment: Sorry, such questions are off topic here (the one this is marked as a duplicate of is grandfathered in by old policy). Feel free to ask in [chat]!